# Reveal custom post ID in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a new column for custom post types that reveals the post ID in the Wordpress DB. The custom posts are Recipes from the WP Ultimate Recipe Plugin. The code below works if I change the hook for just posts, but even with the Plugin Developers advice on which hooks of his to use, it won't work...

```
add_filter( 'manage_recipe_posts_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column', 5 );
add_action( 'manage_recipe_posts_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content', 5, 2 );


function revealid_add_id_column( $columns ) {
$columns['revealid_id'] = 'ID';
return $columns;
}

function revealid_id_column_content( $column, $id ) {
  if( 'revealid_id' == $column ) {
    echo $id;
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
function add_cpt_columns( $columns ) {

    $column_meta = array( 'your-column-slug' => 'your column name' );
    //column rearrange 
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 3, true ) + $column_meta + array_slice( $columns, 3, null, true );
    return $columns;    
}

function custom_custom_cpt_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'your-column-slug' :
            // your process
            break;
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-custom-post-type_columns', 'add_cpt_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_custom-post-type_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_custom_cpt_column', 10, 2 );
```